# RestSharp проблема с куками

Tags: c#, http, cookie, redirect

Здравствуйте. Нужно получить куки после редиректа. Через снифер видно что редирект срабатывает и запрос перескакивает на другую страницу и получаются куки, но в respons'е их нет. В чем проблема?

Мой код:

```
public static async Task<IRestResponse> GetAsyncHttp(string url, List<Cookie> cookies)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(url)
        {
            UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0",
            FollowRedirects = true
        };
        var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET);
        foreach (var cookie in cookies)
        {
            request.AddCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
        }
        var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось использованием Cookie не в request'е, а в самом RestClient, вот так:

```
client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Вместо

```
request.AddCookie("name", "value");
```